# VB.NET How do I make program draggable by a panel?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have been looking around how to do this, but cannot find anything. I have tried almost everything and have resulted to this. Can anyone help me? If you have not caught on, I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio.

Comment: I think you are searching for a borderless app? Then try FormBorderStyle = None.

Comment: No, I want the program to be able to be dragged around by a panel I have placed

Comment: You need to clarify your question to get a useful answer. Do you mean you want to move your main form around the screen based on right, left, up and down buttons placed inside a panel in your form?

Comment: I guess so, I want the program to be able to be moved around like a normal program, but when you try moving the panel.

Comment: You can use code like in [this PAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65176507/2330053), just convert it for VB.Net...

Answer (score 0):

I found code that I left in another program, seems to work fine with me.

Private isMouseDown As Boolean = False
Private mouseOffset As Point

```
' Left mouse button pressed
Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        ' Get the new position
        mouseOffset = New Point(-e.X, -e.Y)
        ' Set that left button is pressed
        isMouseDown = True
    End If
End Sub

' MouseMove used to check if mouse cursor is moving
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If isMouseDown Then
        Dim mousePos As Point = Control.MousePosition
        ' Get the new form position
        mousePos.Offset(mouseOffset.X, mouseOffset.Y)
        Me.Location = mousePos
    End If
End Sub

' Left mouse button released, form should stop moving
Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        isMouseDown = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope it works!

Twisty.